# Search for the multiple string and print it to file in order

Tags: scripting, perl, search, string

I have a data as below, and I need to filter out the Author with "file changes and Lines Modified/Added  Lines Deleted" And I need to separately print it to file with respect to Authors. If there are same authors for multiple commits they need to be be grouped together and printed to a file. I have written the program as below but need to sort with respect to Author.

```
********************************************************************************
Data
********************************************************************************
commit dbegafada..
Author: abc <abc@xy12.com>
Commit: abc <abc@xy12.com>
Merge

      CR1514 - MEMODOK and topWedge merge top planet

    Change-Id: MIG60dfdof5214ab47e39ba9b291c55b458649335cb16

/framework/base/xyc/a3.c
 Lines Modified/Added - 2 Lines Deleted - 1

/frameworks/based/xycpog/ae3.c
 Lines Modified/Added - 5 Lines Deleted - 4

/secure/basedfd/xyc/adf3.c
 Lines Modified/Added - 12 Lines Deleted - 2


commit 45eeertdbegafada..
Author: loxzv <loxzv@xy12.com>
Commit: loxzv <loxzv@xy12.com>
Merge: Pure and greed issue fixed
    Pure and greed issue

    Change-Id: IG6fdof5214abe39ba9b291c55b458649335c....

/frameworks/base-log/xysc/ba3.c
 Lines Modified/Added - 12 Lines Deleted - 9

/security/cops/xdsycpog/ae3.c
 Lines Modified/Added - 5 Lines Deleted - 4

/Nosecure/coper/xyc/adff3.h
 Lines Modified/Added - 12 Lines Deleted - 4


commit 45eeertdbegafada..
Author: loxzv <loxzv@xy12.com>
Commit: loxzv <loxzv@xy12.com>
Merge: Memory leak fixes are allowed

   CRT56 Memory leak fixes are allowed

    Change-Id: IG6fdof5214abe3dfdo0343dsssdfds9335c..b...

/inputs/base-log/xysc/bda3.c
 Lines Modified/Added - 12 Lines Deleted - 9

/security/cops/xdsycpog/beae3.h
 Lines Modified/Added - 5 Lines Deleted - 4

/fullysecure/golden/xyclub/srcGold.c
 Lines Modified/Added - 12 Lines Deleted - 4



commit 45eeertdbegafada..
Author: navzv <navzv@xy12.com>
Commit: Gerrit Code Review
Merge: cold act app release

   Merge cold act app release with service app

    Change-Id: IG6fdof5214lkode..9ba9b2dfdfd91c5586...

/goldenrule/base-less/copycat/batcat3.c
 Lines Modified/Added - 12 Lines Deleted - 9

/security/flops/justhog/state.c
 Lines Modified/Added - 15 Lines Deleted - 3

/Nosecure/method/value/dadff3.h
 Lines Modified/Added - 10 Lines Deleted - 7
```

---

My Program

---

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;


open(INFILE, "</home/symbol/data.txt") or die "Cannot open the file\n";
open(OUTFILE,">/home/symbol/Result1.txt") or die "Can’t open subjects file\n";

while ( my $line = <INFILE> )
{

# To filter out the Modified (M), Added(A) & Deleted(D) Lines in the log file.
            if ($line =~ /^M|^A|^D/ ) {
               if ($line !~ /Merge|Author/) {
                  print OUTFILE $line;
                  }
            }
            if ($line =~ /^M|^A|^D/) {
               my $nextLine = <INFILE>;
               if ($line !~ /Merge|Author|Commit/) {
                  print OUTFILE $nextLine; 
               }

            }

# Condition to print the Lines with M, A & D details.
            if ($line =~ /^ Lines/) {
               print OUTFILE $line;          
            }

# Condition to search for "Author:"
  if ($line =~ /^Author:/){
         print OUTFILE "\n****************************************************  AUTHOR MODIFIED/ADDED/DELETED FILES DETAILS  *******************************************************\n";
         print OUTFILE $line;
   }

 }

close INFILE;
close OUTFILE;
```

Comment: @Nav Please use 3 argument open function and use append mode `>>` for output file. Avoid bareword file handles. Consider using `'*' x 52` for printing stars. why do you use `/^M|^A|^D/` regex twice?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you want to create a hash with authors for keys and arrays for hash values.  You then push an author's file change lines onto the array which has the author's name for a hash key.

After processing the file into the hash, you would use the hash to create the output document.

You could sort the hash keys first in order to output the authors in alphabetical order.